# Raising a thinner tile to be level with a thicker tile

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, mortar

I set all my tiles on the bathroom floor not realizing how much the thinset mortar would add to the height of the floor. I have a curbless shower and the tile I chose for the shower floor is half the thickness of the bathroom floor tiles - I’m 3/16 off.

Can I just build that up with mortar to raise the shower tiles up to the height of the bathroom floor tiles?

I want a smooth transition from the bathroom floor into the shower with no lip.

Comment: A smooth transition to the shower means you'll have to mop the water every time you take a shower. I put a 10mm lip in mine, no such issue.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can build it up.

If you are 3/16" off you might just want to use a 3/16 or 1/4 grooved trowel.

Trowel the full area leaving the ridges, wait for it to setup and then fill in the grooves.

Then just trowel like normal for your thinner tiles.

Comment: Sorry to gravedig — for the second part “fill in the grooves”, should the filled in section get setup before troweling like normal?

Comment: yes I'd let the grooves setup first.  Generally when you trowel for setting tiles the ridges are meant to squish down when you push the tiles into them and the ridges should go in one direction so the air can easily be pushed out.  I think it would just end up being extra messy and hard if you didn't let the grooves setup first.